# ASP.NET Razor how to output raw string immediately next to variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to do this:

```
Our app is called: @AppSettings.AppName
```

How can I put a full stop at the end of the sentence here? Do I need to encapsulate the @ output in something?

Comment: explain **full stop**. I'm clearly missing something since you seem to have the answer in your code sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use tags `<text> </text>`

```
Our app is called: @AppSettings.AppName<text>.</text>
```